# What does the phrase "in plan" mean in this Wikipedia page? (is this a typo?)

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> In architecture, a quadrangle (or colloquially, a quad) is a space or a courtyard, usually rectangular (square or oblong) **in plan**, the sides of which are entirely or mainly occupied by parts of a large building (or several smaller buildings).

The word "plan" is a noun, therefore I believe it to be a typo (no article). Another word that comes to mind is the word "plane" which is an adjective as well as a noun:

TFD def: noun

1. Mathematics A surface containing all the straight lines that connect any two points on it.
2. A flat or level surface.

TFD def: adjective

1. Mathematics Of or being a figure lying in a plane: a plane curve.
2. Flat; level. See Synonyms at level.

But these also don't fit for me somehow.

Comment: ??  a plan is *a plan* ... like a map is a map and a photo is a photo and a blueprint is a blueprint. It's incredibly straightforward.

Comment: @Fattie Who is that comment addressed to? This is a site for **people learning English**; that naturally means that many of the answers seem "incredibly straightforward" to native speakers.

Comment: I was addressing CanadianYankee's comment.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the context of architecture, 'in plan' means 'as viewed from above' (it's the same as 'bird's eye view'). It's because building plans are drawn as if you're looking at them from above. So 'rectangular in plan' means that the building is the shape of a rectangle when you look at it from a bird's eye view.

Comment: OP wants to know why no article is used before "plan." Please explain.

Comment: And it is contrasted with _elevation_ which is the view from one of the sides, hence _front elevation_ and so on.

Comment: I'm not satisfied that my explanation for why 'plan' doesn't need an article was correct. I know it follows the same grammar rule as these examples: 'The house is red in colour' 'The music is pleasant in tone' 'The subject is smooth in texture' 'The quadrangle is rectangular in plan.' But I'll have to leave the explanation to someone who understands it better.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect the underlying phrase is "plan view", which in the architectural and drafting contexts, means, more or less, "as viewed from above". So, I would guess that the OPs phrase "in plan" is short for "in plan view", and success since "plan" here is an adjective, it doesn't take "the".

Comment: I can't edit my comments, or I'd delete the word "success" from my final sentence.

Comment: @Dale Hagglund: You can't edit your comment, but you can delete it and replace it with a corrected version. (Copy the comment text into your clipboard before deleting it.)

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Thanks, I should have been able to figure that out. The error's not egregious, so I think I'll leave it alone.

Comment: @AnonFNV "plan" in an adjective here. The noun following "plan" would be "view", but since it is the only noun possible in the context it is omitted. You don't say "this shirt is available in *the* black, *the* white or *the* blue".

Comment: @DaleHagglund It is definitely short for "plan view", as opposed to "elevation [view]", "isometric [view]", and "perspective [view]", among others. As in, "In plan, we can see the length of this drainage line, while over here in elevation we see the height of the windows."

Comment: @alephzero I agree with others that even if "plan" is short for "plan view", it is being used as a noun here; expanding to "in plan view" wouldn't change the grammar. I think it's equivalent to "The plan of the building is rectangular", where "plan" is clearly a noun. Your colour example is not equivalent, because "black" is the value, not the aspect; the equivalent would be "this shirt is black in colour" = "the colour of this shirt is black".

Comment: @DaleHagglund - if you "don't know for sure" best to delete your comment.  It's not "short" for anything (what does that even mean?) any more than "red in color" is "short" for something. The confusion here is staggering.

Comment: This QA is long in confusion, short in facts.

Comment: @ToddWilcox it is definitely *not* " ' short ' " for anything.  If you believe it is, tell me now what "red in color" is short for.

Comment: @Fattie “Red in color” is the **long** form of just “red”. Seems like you’re on some kind of crusade about this - not sure why. I’ve had three years of training in technical illustration and won awards. In that world, “plan” is a shorter way of saying “plan view”. So… you’re just wrong. If you don’t know what the phrase “short for” means then I think you might be the person who is lacking understanding of the facts here.

Comment: There are two different ways of explaining the sentence structure. You could say 'in plan' is an abbreviation of 'in plan view'. Or you could say 'rectangular in plan' is structured like 'red in colour', where 'plan' is a property of the building. I don't know which interpretation is correct (they've actually been posted as two separate answers now, and they are both getting votes), and I don't think it's worth arguing about since they both work. You can't really mix the two interpretations together though. I've commented OP's question "why does plan have no article?" onto both answers.

Comment: @Fattie "If, bizarrely, you have never heard it before, please do not add wildly, bizarrely, confusing comments.", "staggeringly misguided, have utterly no connection to anything", etc. Do you ever stop to read your comments before posting them, and consider your tone?

Comment: @alephzero - "You don't say "this shirt is available in the black, the white or the blue". People working in UK shops say that kind of thing.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know the technical term for it, but I believe this is a common pattern for nouns describing *aspects* of something:

- the sky was red in colour
- he was stocky in build
- it was square in shape

The pattern is that "X (concrete noun) is Y (adjective) in Z (aspect noun)" means roughly "the Z (aspect noun) of X (concrete noun) is Y (adjective)". So "the sky was red in colour" means "the colour of the sky is red", and "the building is rectangular in plan" means "the plan of the building is rectangular".

The "plan" in this case is a noun meaning something like "shape as seen from above", as opposed to "profile" or "elevation", meaning "shape as seen from the side or front". As others have pointed out, this comes from the architectural meaning of "plan", for a flat diagram of a building in such an overhead view.

Comment: Also to be noted is that, geometrically speaking, "in plan" might be as opposed to "in profile". For example, "[The Taj Mahal](https://cdnb.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/013/485/013/large/svetlana-chubko-taj-mahal-with-logo.jpg?1539802321_) is roughly rectangular **in plan** (viewed from above) but has a very complex shape **in profile** (viewer from the side)"

Comment: This reminds me of that Shakespeare line which I only remember/know because Picard quoted it to Q: "What a piece of work is a man! How noble in reason, how infinite in faculty! In form and moving how express and admirable! In action how like an angel, in apprehension how like a god!"

Comment: I think this "value in aspect" pattern is a useful way of understanding the grammar, but is there a technical reason why 'plan,' 'colour,' and 'build' have no article in this pattern?

Comment: @AnonFNV "Why" is always a slippery question, and it's tempting to say "because that's how it works", but I'm sure linguists would attempt to fit it into some wider framework. Unfortunately, I don't know a name for this construction, so don't know where to start looking for such analyses.

Answer (score 8):

In this context "plan" is an adjective describing a drawing or view and is distinct from "section" and "elevation". See [Plan, Section, Elevation Architectural Drawings Explained](https://fontanarchitecture.com/plan-section-elevation/)
In that phrase "in plan" is an abbreviation of "in plan view".

Comment: "A *plan drawing* is a drawing on a horizontal plane showing a view from above. An *Elevation drawing* is drawn on a vertical plane showing a vertical depiction. A *section drawing* is also a vertical depiction, but one that cuts through space to show what lies within."

Comment: the web site is crap.  "in plan view" is meaningless.  "in plan" is an utterly normal phrase, such as "yellow in color" or "lost in love" or "big in football".

Comment: OP has asked why 'plan' has no article. If 'in plan' is an abbreviation of 'in plan view', why does 'plan view' have no article?

Answer (score 0):

A plan is:

[image]

aka blueprint; a schematic drawing of something from overhead, rather like a map; a piece of paper with marks on it indicating the arrangement, layout, of the building or device in question.

Comment: This doesn't explain the structure of the sentence. You can't say *"it is rectangular in map", or "...in blueprint", so those comparisons are not helpful. Knowing that it means "overhead view" is certainly important, but already covered by other answers, which also explain the rest of the grammar.

Comment: Suit yourself.  The OP doesn't know what a plan is. It's not complicated. (Notice the incorrect definitions given in the question.)

Comment: ? You often say, exactly, such-and-such in map, or, such-and-such in blueprint.  (For example, "it looked awesome in blueprint".)

Comment: "it looked awesome in blueprint" sounds awkward to my ear, but I can understand what it might mean. So, is your interpretation of "the building is rectangular in plan" something like "the building is rectangular on the architect's blueprint, but might not be in real life?"

Comment: I'm still baffled by your last comment, and surprised to see two people apparently agreed with it. I genuinely can't imagine what "in map" could even mean. Maybe I'm lacking in imagination, or there's some regional variation here?

Comment: it's no different whatsoever from a zillion similar phrases, "it sounded good in theory".  sure, for many words it may be more common to include an article.  for example a car designer will say "this looked better in the clay" although you might say "this was better in clay".   **but surely any native speaker would know** there are HEAPS of cases like red in color, good in theory, square in plan, pointy in elevation, lucky in love where you don't use one.  "blah in plan" is a wholly commonplace phrase, google a zillion examples

Comment: Yes, I agree that "it is X in Y" is a common construction, and have written an answer explaining what I think that construction means (the only answer on this page you haven't left a comment criticising). However, I don't think you can apply it to any noun, and I can't think how any sentence could be formed from the template "it is [something] in map", any more than you could have "it is [something] in dog". That's why I don't think comparing "plan" to "map" is helpful for explaining this sentence.

Comment: "x in color" is wholly commonplace (google to check); "x in plan" is wholly commonplace (google to check); "x in elevation" is wholly commonplace (google to check).  For the OP (problem 1 the OP faces), the two **definitions** mentioned in the OP are utterly irrelevant to the definition at hand.  For the OP (problem 2 the OP faces) "... in plan" is an utterly, utterly commonplace phrase in English. It is not "short" for something, it is completely, utterly, idiomatic and commonplace (google to check) - just like very many other similar forms ("in spirit, in heart, in color, etc etc")

Comment: I suggest you read my answer, then reread my comments. That comment shows that so far you have done neither.